# How to add blank/empty page after bibliography? (Alternative to \newpage or \afterpage)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, appendices, blank-page, emptypage

I need an empty page, without numbering, and I want it to appear above my appendix, and below my reference list. The appendix is the last thing to appear in the file, and the references are second to last and they should be separated by an empty page.

I have tried suggestions to similar issues, but none have worked thus far when placed alongside `\printbibliogrophy`. Even though they work in other locations in the code.

I have tried:

```
    \newpage\thispagestyle{empty}\mbox{}
```

And with this in the preamble:

> ```
> \usepackage{afterpage}
> \newcommand\blankpage{%
>     \null
>     \thispagestyle{empty}%
>     \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
>     \newpage}
> ```

I have tried:

```
\afterpage{\blankpage}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\makeatletter 
\def\mblx@yearfrom{-1000} 
\def\mblx@yearto{3000}

\newrobustcmd*{\setcheckfromtorange}[2]{%
   \def\mblx@yearfrom{#1}%   
\def\mblx@yearto{#2}% 
}

\defbibcheck{fromto}{%
   \iffieldint{year}
    {\ifnumless{\thefield{year}}{\mblx@yearfrom}
       {\skipentry}
       {\ifnumgreater{\thefield{year}}{\mblx@yearto}
          {\skipentry}
          {}}}
    {\skipentry}} 
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}   
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  } 
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 
\nocite{*}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{afterpage} 
\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}

\usepackage{appendix}   

\begin{document}

\section{The text} 
\lipsum[1-3] 
\newpage

\printbibliography[check=fromto,title={References}]

% This is where i want to add the empty page without numbering.  
% Oddly the mbox solution works in the MWE.

\newpage

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\appendix 
\appendixpage 
\begin{appendices} 
\lipsum[1-3] 
\end{appendices}
    \newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be much easier for me to start tackle your problem if you could reduce the code as much as possible while still making sure that the document can be compiled and reproduce the issue. Large preambles like the one shown in this question always demotivate me. A very big issue is that we don't have your files  `Dokument/1-Forside.tex` and so we can't even run the shown code at all (without errors). Please try to get rid of included files or - if they are absolutely necessary - provide dummy contents for the required files.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking for with so many words is what is usually called an MWE on this site: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864.

Comment: I have now tried to do that. I will add the new simplified code in the question!

Comment: Does this help: `\newpage\hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage`

Comment: Yes, it does! Thank you John! Do you mind explaining why this works? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [John](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/119566/john) for the solution to my problem!

```
\newpage\hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
```

As can be seen, the solution is to add `\hbox{}` and remove `\mbox{}` and put `\newpage` in its former location.

Why this works, and my former code does not, I do not know. If anyone wants to explain, I would very much appreciate it!